# Retrieve post variable sent via Ajax in Django

Tags: ajax, django, post

I'm processing a table of banking/statement entries that have been exported from another system via a CSV file. They are imported into a view and checked for duplicates before being presented to the user in a HTML table for final review.

Once checked they are sent via AJAX to the server so they can be added into a Django model.  Everything is working OK including CSRF but I cannot access the POSTed variable although I can see it!

Unfortunately making a hidden form isn't viable as there are 80+ rows to process.

My **Javascript** looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '......./ajax/handleImports/',
    data: entriesObj,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.response && data.response) {
            console.log("Update was successful");
            console.log(data.entries)
        } else {  ... } 
    },
    error: function() { ... }
```

where entriesObj is

```
var entriesObj = JSON.stringify({ "newentries": newEntries });
console.log(entriesObj)
```

and when dumped to console.log looks like:

```
{"newentries":[{"Include":"","Upload ID":"0","Date":"2019-01-09", ... }
```

Now in **view.py** when I return the whole request.POST object as data.entries using

```
context['entries'] = request.POST
return JsonResponse(context)
```

I get

```
{"{"newentries":[{"Include":"","Upload ID":"0","Date":"2019-01-09", ... }
```

but if I try and retrieve newentries with:

```
entries = request.POST.get('newentries', None)
context['entries'] = entries
return JsonResponse(context)
```

the console.log(data.entries) will output null?

How am I supposed to access the POSTed entriesObj?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is JSON, you need to get the value from `request.body` and parse it.

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
entries = data.get('newentries')
```

Comment: Thank you for the speed and accuracy of this answer.  Everything is easy once you have done it the first time!  Will accept etc. shortly.